# PHP regex to accept Japanese and english languages

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to create a regex to filter only alphabets or numbers from English and Japanese languages. This is what I have tried,

`preg_match('/(?![\n\r])[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF][^\x4e00-\x9fa0)]/u', $value)`

But I am not getting the desired result. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please precise what you are doing? Matching words, or removing chars, or validating whole strings? Could you please provide a sample string or two with expected result? Just FYI, any Unicode letter can be matched with `\p{L}` and any digit can be matched with `\p{N}`, or you may use `'~[\p{L}\d]~u'` to match any Unicode letter or digit.

Comment: What is the "desired result"?

Comment: I guess it is one of the cases when using a regex "only doubles trouble". Manu, please explain what you are doing.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/), I think this is really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`unicode character properties`](http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.unicode.php)
Also you may have a look on this website which contains some other regex examples http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/

*Updated character list based on @Álvaro González notice about the three alphabets.*

this regex should do what you expect :

```
preg_match('/[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}]+/u', $value)
```

`\p{L}` will match any letter, `\p{N}` any number and `\p{Katakana}` will match any Katakana char etc...

You may need to add word delimiters into the accepted characters if you are not matching single words

Comment: The [Japanese writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system) uses three alphabets: Kanji, Hiragana and Katakana. PCRE does not seem to support Kanji.

Comment: I admit that I don't know well the japanese writing system... thank you for this additionnal information about the three alphabets

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález by looking here http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/ it seems that all three alphabets are supported

Comment: Why use `(?![\n\r])` here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The op used it so I keept it. perhaps it is not really needed

Comment: You do not need the `(?![\n\r])` as it was used to restrict a more generic pattern. E.g. `(?![\n\r])\s` matches any whitespace but CR and LF symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex checks the line is not Japanese language:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[\x{3041}-\x{3096}\x{30a1}-\x{30fc}\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]+$/u', $line)){
    // ...
}
```

You can find more in the document:
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.html