# Target URLs with special characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with HTML, and I target image URLs like this:

```
$regex = '#([a-z,:=\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))#i';
```

Works fine with:

```
https://example.com/image.jpg
```

But when a URL has a special character, like:

```
https://example.com/ストスト.jpg
```

It doesn't match. [See test](https://ideone.com/VixE18)!

How do I alter the regex so it matches with URLs that have these special characters?

Comment: No need of escaping meta characters inside a character class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula

Comment: Also, are you sure it doesn't match? https://3v4l.org/ZudaJ

Comment: You need to look for everything includeing unicode characters - something like https://regex101.com/r/wdabX7/1

Comment: @waterloomatt Can you post an answer using my regex code as a base?

Comment: (\p{L}+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))

Comment: @njank That only matches the file name and not the whole URL.

Comment: .*?(\p{L}+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))

Comment: Since you tagged the question with PHP you might want to try checking the URL with an [endsWith()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php) function.

Comment: Use the `u` flag and use `$regex = '#[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#iu`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP regex to accept Japanese and english languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586145/php-regex-to-accept-japanese-and-english-languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the character class you don't have to escape the `,` and the `:`. You also don't have to escape the `/` if you use a different delimiter like `#`.

You could shorten the pattern to

```
[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNYLJd/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/0hdkb)

If you want to find the href from the anchors, I suggest using a parser instead.

The pattern including the `u` unicode flag:

```
$regex = '#[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#iu
```

For example (using anchors `^` and `$` to prevent getting partial matches)

```
$input = <<<HTML
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example1.jpg">
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/ストスト.jpg">
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example3.jpg">
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example3.bak">
HTML;

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($input, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
$regex = '#^[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$#iu';

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $res = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    if (preg_match($regex, $res)) {
        echo "Valid url: $res" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Invalid url: $res" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Valid url: https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example1.jpg
Valid url: https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/ストスト.jpg
Valid url: https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example3.jpg
Invalid url: https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example3.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to use a unicode flag on the regex and see if those characters are matched or not, like this:

`$regex = '#([a-zストスト,:=\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))#iu';`

notice the `u` at the end of the regex ( it refers to unicode )

Obviously, you can add the range of your alphabet if its supported.

i.e. like this `ス-ト`

An other approach could be to add the complete alphabet within the regex, right after your a-z parameter. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787716/regular-expression-for-japanese-characters) also.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment that refers to any foreign character, the best thing I can think of, is to use the parameter `\w` which means every word character, and add the `u` flag at the end of your regex.

This means that it could be `$regex = '#([\w,:=\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))#iu';`

With this regex, your 2 examples work fine. Waiting for your response :)

Comment: But my target is not specifically these characters `ストスト` but all foreign language characters. Can you please edit your answer on how I would do that using my regex code as reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
'#([\p{L},:=\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))#i'
```

This works for all foreign language characters.
Hope this could help

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, please [see this](https://ideone.com/U1MH2A)...

Comment: $domain is Undefined